# Bad-case for parsing html table with R

Tags: r, parsing, html-table, rcurl

I faced a problem with parsing a html table using RCurl and XML in R. Method readHTMLTable returns 0-length named list for table.

The problem is that `readHTMLTable()` doesn't recognize the parsing result as a HTML table, but it is one.

Here is a R code:

```
library("RCurl")
library("XML")

plant<-"APCHC"
market<-"MED"
product<-"GAP"
start_date<-"7.1.2014"
end_date<-"14.7.2014"

curl <- getCurlHandle()

url<-URLencode("http://www.kortes.com/index/nb/index.php")
headers <- c(
  'Accept' = '*/*',
  'x-requested-with' = 'XMLHttpRequest',
  'User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/4.0',
  'Content-Type' = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
  'Accept-Encoding' = 'gzip, deflate'
)
body<- paste("codex=getForTable&val1=",plant,"&val2=",market,"&val3=",product,"&date1=",start_date,"&date2=",end_date, sep="")
reader = basicTextGatherer()
hh = basicHeaderGatherer()
res = curlPerform(url=url, httpheader= headers, postfields=body,     writefunction=reader$update, headerfunction = hh$update, curl=curl, .encoding="UTF-8")


kortes<-readHTMLTable(reader$value())

>length(kortes)
>[1] 0
```

Please, tell me which method is suitable to solve this problem.
Thanks!

Comment: I cannot run your example code, some objects are missing...

Comment: I have run this code again and there were no errors or missing objects...

Comment: So the problem is solved???

Comment: @Richie Cotton upgraded the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of `reader$value()` are just the `tr` elements, not the whole table.  Try:

```
readHTMLTable(paste0("<table>", reader$value(), "</table>"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can considerably simplify your life by using httr:

```
library("httr")
library("XML")

r <- POST(
  "http://www.kortes.com/index/nb/index.php",
  body = list(
    val1 = "APCHC", # plant
    val2 = "MED", # market
    val3 = "GAP", # product
    date1 = "7.1.2014", # start date
    date2 = "14.7.2014"
  )
)
stop_for_status(r)

kortes <- readHTMLTable(content(r, encoding = "UTF-8"))
length(kortes)
#> [1] 4
```